# How to go to the position of spotlight's result?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I use the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to search a file, you see the below image, but how can I go to the file's position?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-enter should do the trick